# LoopingSelector in UWP (Universal Windows Applications)?

Tags: .net, xaml, win-universal-app, uwp

I know there is a class that is called [LoopingSelector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.loopingselector.aspx), but what's the point of it? It's sealed, doesn't have public constructors. Nothing. Also, there is a LoopingSelectorItem. The same.

**Why?!**

I want something similar to its usage in WP7:
http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/wp7-loopingselector-in-depth--part1-visual-structure-and-api

Comment: These controls are everywhere in Windows. Why is it so hard to use them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this custom control can help? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mim/archive/2013/04/16/winrt-create-a-custom-itemspanel-for-an-itemscontrol.aspx

Comment: Well let us know if you make any progress :) but I would think the code should be uwp compatible!

Comment: OK, it works, but the code is thought to work vertically, only :(

Comment: Hmm to be honest I never looked at the real implementation, but the new Panel that is being created, can't you set an orientation somewhere? Or maybe on the base class?

Comment: No, unfortunately it's not so simple. It's hardcoded inside the panel itself. I wonder if it's easy to make it have 2 different orientations, like `StackPanel`.

Comment: Ok that is a shame, would have been a great control if you could just set the orientation through a dependency property :(

Comment: This link exists but neither the video not the sample work

Answer (score 3):

It's one of the primitive controls used by other controls. You can see it's template definition here: 
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\10.0.10240.0\Generic\generic.xaml"

In the template it's a scrollviewer and an up and down repeat button. You'll also find the 'LoopingSelectorItem' template which is really just a content presenter.

However you won't find any controls in there that's actually using it, which is somewhat odd.

Comment: So the LoopingSelector only share the name with the prevous WP7 counterpart. Isn't it? My goal is not to reinvent the wheel to achieve what the DatePicker control does: infinite scrolling where the selected item is in the middle. Do you think there is a built-in panel or control to achive this effect? Thanks, Morten for the info :D

Comment: Interestingly enough, there is not way to create the control.

Comment: it really is odd. seems that if I want to use the same control being used in the timepicker control but for 0-100 (or even 0-60), I'd have to write the thing all over again..

Comment: looping selector is used inside the TimePickerFlyout. To be more precise inside TimePickerFlyoutPresenter